# Oracle: Finding Terminal RDP Client Name

Tags: oracle, environment-variables, rdp

To understand the question, consider this scenario. Two employees log in to an Application server via Windows Remote Desktop Client. Both use the same username e.g., Salesmen. From the Application Server, they launch the ERP application that connects to a Database (located in the Database Server).

Now, if we want to record a log of some of the activities made by each individual salesmen, we can't use SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER') in Oracle because it will return the same OS name i.e., Salesmen.

What I am looking for is to know the Terminal RDP Client Name, who has logged in as "Salesmen" into the Application Server. I tried dbms_system.get_env to get %CLIENTNAME% environment variable but it is also of no use as it is returning null. Is there any other way of identifying who is remotely logged in to the Server having Oracle Client..

Comment: Did you try looking in v$session ? there is a machine and terminal property.

Comment: Yes I tried v$session but it is giving the information about the terminal that I am using to log-on to the database server. The issue is that users connect to the Terminal through RDP and I want to know the IP or PC-Name of the Terminal that initiated the RDP..

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that.